# In CodenameOne, is the argument for ConnectionRequest.setTimeout in milliseconds or seconds?

Tags: network-programming, codenameone

I have an extremely slow and unreliable internet connection.  Should I set a timeout, or not?  What is the unit of measurement? I understand the default is "-1" which sets no timeout.   I guess the server will still impose a timeout of some sort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The timeout is in milliseconds however it's a connection timeout that is implicitly canceled once a connection is made. So if the server is slow but you were still able to connect you won't get a timeout.

This is important for features such as streaming where we don't want a timeout to happen. You can kill unresponsive connections or use lower level API's such as websockets to get more control.